# Typescript: cartesian product of two generic arrays results to wrong type inferred

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote a simple Cartesian product implementation in Typescript, but the type inferred is not what I have expected:

```
export function cartesianProduct<X, Y> (a: X[], b: Y[]): Array<[X, Y]> {
    return a.flatMap(x => b.map(y => [x, y]));
}
```

[image]

As you can see, the inferred type is `(X | Y)[][] instead of [X, Y][]`. This seems weird to me because `[x, y]` should have type `[X, Y]` (x is of X type and y is of Y type).
Any idea why I am getting this type error and how to fix?

Comment: "*`[x, y]` should have type `[X, Y]`*" - no, it has type `(X | Y)[]`. Use `[x, y] as const` to get the tuple type.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, in that case I have also to change the output type to `Array<readonly [X, Y]>`

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript generally infers [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `[x, y]` to have [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) instead of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  If you want to change this, you need to give the type checker context for which it to infer the type differently.  There are various ways to go about this (such as a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), or using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) with the `as` operator, or by manually specifying the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument to `map` as `map<[X, Y]>`).

Currently the approach I'd most recommend is to use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator); if you write `expr satisfies Type` it will tell the compiler to use `Type` as context for inferring `expr`'s type.  If it can infer a compatible type it will; otherwise it will produce an error, so the `satisfies` operator is type safe in a way that a type assertion is not.

So all you need to do is this:

```
function cartesianProduct<X, Y>(a: X[], b: Y[]): Array<[X, Y]> {
    return a.flatMap(x => b.map(y => [x, y] satisfies [X, Y]));
}
```

And it works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG9oF8BQpIwMIAsBLEAE2gQA8AXBAOxJngiVUw0NpoCcAzMYJEwS4qAey4oM0adFoIA7gAoAlAC44iANwY2IBFWgAjRCPHqhpiQF4NzTdAD0D6PPEBrGDw4IMegwWISS3MTMWtoANJ7J2hgUQBbAAdwDhg5Qip8BAlRADds8ESIDCA=#code/FDD0oAgFwCwSwM4URAZnAdgUwgIwK5QQBOWAjvnKUgIYQA2cUU9OpqNAxlAPbGYBzYFgAeABz5FU+DNzg8METjWJQsCODQwAFYjwAm+bgEEAPAA0ANBACaAPgAUNAFwRzAbQC613K5teASldjYmIaAE9TUhp9BXpwiHcrW087CABvYAhskiwofGJFGgA6VHoaKABZGjEHEQgAXjTcYoBbGocEpsSRa3DPCBokTgUEKACAgG5gAF8QcGh4JBQsIYSCIgweIihwsRwEGlQcTp58JTP6fQgAd341QaR3bAA3LGJrV-eBrWvYHBGrTEcFYxFul30GAA5ERlFBODBkONhOJJGgZHIFEoVGoNFpdAYjFAAEIWaz2JyuDzePB+QLBUIRUxJcmpDJZHKkfKFQalcpVDr1botdq1Lppdy9CD9R6JZI2TwTaZzMCQWAoFACHgGPCEJEQWLqaFEGj0G4RJACLDYMKMABeWBRElU6NkUHkimUqnUmh0ekM3AAwmTbI4XG4vD46YqGWFIiyUmlMjlctyinyKtVakLmm0asz5alOo0JVL+krZvNIK0EqRAa1rfoKh6nWjpG6PdjvXi-YTuAAREMU8PUqO2ekQEJxguspMc7JcgrpsqZwUlvB5sXryV9AaHd0IdDqOWsisqoA)

Comment: Why isn't "as const" enough to infer output type? I haven't tested it because I'm on my phone but I'm surprised it doesn't. What is the output type produced by "as const" on its own?

Comment: It infers as `readonly [X, Y]` which is not assignable to `[X, Y]`, so `as const` on its own isn't a direct solution. You can set the return type annotation of `cartesianProduct` to `readonly [X, Y]` as well, though.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is confused about your types. Your code makes it seem like you want an array which returns more arrays which have a mix of your X and Y. However, it seems you want an array of pairs which would be [X, Y].

To fix your error, you would have to define that the inner arrays should be [X, Y].
Like this:

```
export function cartesianProduct<X, Y>(a: X[], b: Y[]): Array<[X, Y]> {
return a.flatMap((x: X) => b.map((y: Y) => [x, y] as [X, Y]));
```

}